# Как на html/css блоками сделать сетку из картинок одинакового размера?

Tags: html, css

Можно ли обойтись без js, чтобы получилось вот так:[image: Сетка из картинок]

Comment: Так можно сделать

Comment: img {float: left; }

Comment: используйте flex-box

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов много. Можете использовать float, можете использовать псевдоэлемент after в конце списка картинок, который будет их равномерно растягивать, либо можете использовать text-align: justify, как пример:

```
<style>
    .img {
        text-align: justify;
        -moz-text-align-last: justify;
        text-align-last: justify;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .img img {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        margin: 5px;
    }
</style>

<div class="img">
    <img src="" alt=""/>
    <img src="" alt=""/>
    <img src="" alt=""/>
</div>
```